# multipart/form-data is not working with apisauce

Tags: reactjs

I am sending a api request which is created through apisauce library as bellow

```
const api = create({
  baseURL: `http://35.247.184.92:3000`,
  timeout: 30000,
});

export const denoiseApi = payload => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', 'test');

  return api.post('/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPES.MULTIPART,
      Accept: 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
};
```

but the Content-Type header is not set to  "multipart/form-data " and formdata also not sent in the request correctly.
See the bellow screenshots

[image]

what i am doing wrong here , why is this happening , how can i correct this.
Please help